# How do I create remote desk access with limitation?

Tags: rdp

I have a desktop that sits in the USA with three users "A" "B" & "C".
Our team works remotely. I want to create a remote desk access for the team for user "B", so they can access anytime and use a specific application installed in there.

I tried to create RDP for the account "B"  by following a few youtube videos and tech blogs but could not create and connect remote access successfully.

Our team works remotely they use their own network. Can anyone help me to create RDP access successfully? Your help is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Your question is very vague and gives nowhere near the information required to give an answer.. How is the desktop connected to the internet? 'Our team works remotely they use their own network' what does this mean? They have their own internet connection or they have their own subnet over VPN or ......

Comment: `I tried to create RDP for the account "B" by following a few youtube videos and tech blogs but could not create and connect remote access successfully.` - I guess we're supposed to know what you did? How about adding User B to the local Remote Desktop Users group o the computer? Have you done that?

Comment: @JamesD I apologize for the bad English! 

I meant they have their own internet connection and do not use VPN.

Comment: @joeqwerty  We have three sign-in accounts (local account on the desktop)- "A", "B" & "C" for the desktop that sits the USA.

And I want to set-up RDP for "B". I followed this video to create the account -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sODsSm5aeyY